# Como ajusta el tamaño de un JTextArea a el tamaño del JFrame

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola estoy realizando un proyecto personal el cual consiste en crear un block de notas estoy usando un JTextArea y un JScrollPane par hacer la parte del texto pero a la hora de agrandar el JFrame el JTextArea se queda pequeño y no se como se pueda hacer para ajustar el tamaño de JTextArea respecto al JFrame
esto es lo que llevo.

Gracias por su tiempo.

```
//Elementos
JTextArea txtarea = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(txtarea);

//Constructor
public interfas() {
    setLayout(null);
    scroll.setBounds(0, 0, 585, 565);

    add(scroll);
}
//Método main
public static void main(String args[]) {
    interfas bloc = new interfas();

    bloc.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
    bloc.setVisible(true);
    bloc.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    bloc.setResizable(true);
}
```

Comment: De entrada con `setBounds` el tamaño del área de texto va a ser fijo; lo que se puede hacer es, en el constructor `interfaz`, quitar el `setLayout(null)` y el `scroll.setBounds(0,0,585,565);`

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funciono